# how to store audio files path in mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, audio

i am struggling to store mp3 files URL/path in my songs table url field. i am using xampp and mysql with phpmyadmin since i have very little knowledge about sql i have no idea how exactly i should refer my mp3 files path to songs table field! my mp3 files are located in Local drive E and this is the address of one of my mp3 file

> E:\Entertainment Lib\Music Library\The Beatles\The Beatles A Hard Day's Night\If I Fell.mp3

but after putting it in database table it doesn't work for me. screenshot of my database table is [here-plz check this](http://postimg.org/image/g2pjf27bt/)
and finally this is the script that i used to fetch random song from my database table

```
 <?php

 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){ 

include_once "ez_sql_core.php";
include_once "ez_sql_mysql.php";
$db = new ezSQL_mysql('root','','test','localhost'); 

$song = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

$artist = $song->artist;
$songname = $song->title;
$url = $song->url;
$separator = '|';
echo $url.$separator.$artist.$separator.$songname;
} 

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        var data = $.ajax({
          url: "/js/getsong.php",
          async: false
         }).responseText;

        var string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");

        $('#artist').html(string[1]);
        $('#songname').html(string[2]);
    },
    ended: function (event) {  
        var data = $.ajax({
          url: "/js/getsong.php",
          async: false
         }).responseText;

        var string = data.split('|');
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: string[0]
        }).jPlayer("play");

        $('#Miaow').html(string[1]);
        $('#Hidden').html(string[2]);
    },
    swfPath: "js/jPlayer",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
});
</script>
```

i will be very thankful to the person who will helps me to solve this problem.

Comment: i dont see the image in your link.

Comment: What is the output of the url? I guess the slashes and apostrophe should be escaped

Comment: image link is working now plz check it again.

Comment: i tried to escape backslashes but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes

```
"E:\\Entertainment Lib\\Music Library\\The Beatles\\The Beatles A Hard Day's Night\\If I Fell.mp3"
```

the \ is an excape character in mysql strings.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work for me. i escaped the slashes but on luck!

Comment: i still dont see the image, can you explain what is not working?

Comment: maybe something wrong with my code because it works fine when i put an online mp3 file address in my database table url field e.g "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3"

Comment: can you post your insert query code and then what is actually ending up in the database?

Comment: actually i trying to store my mp3 file path to database which is on my E localdrive and the fetch that mp3 to play on my site with jplayer but it doesn't work although it works fine when i put an online mp3 file path name!

Comment: is your site running on your local machine?

Comment: yes i used localhost developing environment "XAMPP"

Comment: can you add a var_dump($song) in your above code and see if the values are correct as you expect?

Comment: now i add var_dump($song) to my code but it doesn't return any thing but online links to mp3 files works fine! maybe my code doesn't best suite when it comes to local drive files system please can you do some modification to my code so it can fetch and play mp3 songs on jplayer?

Comment: var_dump($song) showed that message http://s10.postimg.org/mpq3u822h/Untitled2.png

Comment: it looks like you have a valid URL => "E:\\Song_Name.mp3" does the mp3 exist at that location?

Comment: is your server set up to allow the correct mime types?
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response